# Web scraping with R, message that Javascript is disabled

Tags: r, web-scraping

Hello I am attempting to webscrape in R and this one particular website is giving me a lot of trouble. I wish to extract the table from here:
https://www.nationsreportcard.gov/profiles/stateprofile?chort=1&sub=MAT&sj=&sfj=NP&st=MN&year=2017

what I have tried

code:

```
url = 'https://www.nationsreportcard.gov/profiles/stateprofile?chort=1&sub=MAT&sj=&sfj=NP&st=MN&year=2017'

webpage = read_html(url)

data = webpage %>% html_nodes('p') %>% html_text()
data
```

Ouput:

```
[1] "\r\n            The page could not be loaded. This web site 
currently does not fully support browsers with \"JavaScript\" disabled. 
Please note that if you choose to continue without enabling 
\"JavaScript\" certain functionalities on this website may not be 
available.\r\n
```

Comment: Java and Javascript aren't the same thing. I'm editing the title accordingly

Answer (score 3):

In this cases, you may want to use [`RSelenium`](https://github.com/ropensci/RSelenium) with `docker` to scrape  a Javascript website

```
require("RSelenium")
require("rvest")
system('docker run -d -p 4445:4444 selenium/standalone-firefox')

remDr <-  RSelenium::remoteDriver(
  remoteServerAddr = "localhost",
  port = 4445L,
  browserName = "firefox"
)

#Start the remote driver
remDr$open()


url = 'https://www.nationsreportcard.gov/profiles/stateprofile? 
chort=1&sub=MAT&sj=&sfj=NP&st=MN&year=2017'

remDr$navigate(url)

doc <- read_html(remDr$getPageSource()[[1]])
table <- doc %>%
         html_nodes(xpath = '//*[@id="gridAvergeScore"]/table') %>%
         html_table(fill=TRUE)

head(table[[1]])

##    JURISDICTION AVERAGE SCORE (0 - 500)              AVERAGE SCORE (0 - 500) ACHIEVEMENT LEVEL PERCENTAGES ACHIEVEMENT LEVEL PERCENTAGES
## 1  JURISDICTION                   Score Difference from National public (NP)             At or above Basic        At or above Proficient
## 2 Massachusetts                     249                                   10                            87                            53
## 3     Minnesota                     249                                   10                            86                            53
## 4         DoDEA                     249                                    9                            91                            51
## 5      Virginia                     248                                    9                            87                            50
## 6    New Jersey                     248                                    9                            87                            50
```

Answer (score 3):

Introducing third-party dependencies increases complexity and hampers reproducibility.

That site uses XHR requests to load the data asynchronously (and, poorly IMO) after the initial page load.

Open up Developer Tools in your browser and then load the page and navigate to Network -> XHR:

[image]

Do a teensy bit of spelunking to get actual, lovely JSON data vs have to use error-prone HTML table parsing:

```
httr::GET(
  "https://www.nationsreportcard.gov/ndedataservice/ChartHandler.aspx?type=sp_state_map_datatable&subject=MAT&cohort=1&year=2017R3&_=2_0"
) -> res

str(xdat <- httr::content(res)$result, 2)
## List of 1
##  $ StateMap_DataTableData:List of 6
##   ..$ FocalJurisdiction: chr "NP"
##   ..$ Title            : chr "Mathematics, Grade 4<br />Difference in average scale scores between all jurisdictions and National public, for"| __truncated__
##   ..$ TableSortPrompt  : chr "Click on column headers to sort data by scores for a student group or score differences"
##   ..$ TableColumns     :List of 7
##   ..$ Statedata        :List of 54
##   ..$ Footnotes        :List of 4


dplyr::bind_rows(xdat$StateMap_DataTableData$Statedata)
## # A tibble: 54 x 11
##    Jurisdiction JurisdictionCode MN    SigDiff SigSymbol AB    AP    MN_FP
##    <chr>        <chr>            <chr> <chr>   <chr>     <chr> <chr> <chr>
##  1 Massachuset… MA               249   10      ▲         87    53    249.…
##  2 Minnesota    MN               249   10      ▲         86    53    248.…
##  3 DoDEA        DS               249   9       ▲         91    51    248.…
##  4 Virginia     VA               248   9       ▲         87    50    248.…
##  5 New Jersey   NJ               248   9       ▲         87    50    247.…
##  6 Wyoming      WY               248   9       ▲         89    51    247.…
##  7 Indiana      IN               247   7       ▲         86    48    246.…
##  8 Florida      FL               246   7       ▲         88    48    246.…
##  9 Nebraska     NE               246   6       ▲         85    49    245.…
## 10 New Hampshi… NH               245   6       ▲         85    48    245.…
## # ... with 44 more rows, and 3 more variables: SigDiff_FP <chr>,
## #   AB_FP <chr>, AP_FP <chr>
```

You can select-away unnecessary columns and `type.convert()` or `readr::type_convert()` to get proper object types.

Also, consider paramer-izing the `GET` request for potential functional use; e.g.

```
httr::GET(
  url = "https://www.nationsreportcard.gov/ndedataservice/ChartHandler.aspx",
  query = list(
    type = "sp_state_map_datatable",
    subject = "MAT",
    cohort = "1",
    year = "2017R3",
    `_` = "2_0"
  )
) -> res
```

^^ could be wrapped in a function with parameters passed to the `query` list elements.