# Issue webscraping a website: not extracting anything

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I am trying to extract data from the following website: 'https://2010-2014.kormany.hu/hu/hirek'. When I try to extract, for example, the articles' links from that website using the following, I got nothing.

```
library(rvest)
library(dplyr)
library(XML)

url <- 'www.2015-2019.kormany.hu/hu/hirek'
links <- read_html(url) %>% html_nodes("div") %>% html_nodes(xpath = '//*[@class="article"]') %>% html_nodes("h2") %>% html_nodes("a") %>% html_attr("href")

links
> character(0)
```

I don't even get anything if I run the following code:

```
links <- read_html(url) %>% html_nodes("div")

links
> character(0)
```

This is very strange since, when I inspect the website, it seems that I should be getting the list of URLs from the code I provided. According to the website's source, there are "div" nodes ('view-source:[https://2015-2019.kormany.hu/hu/hirek'](https://2015-2019.kormany.hu/hu/hirek%27)). Does anyone know what I could be doing wrong?

Comment: It seems like the data comes from javascript. Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53088983/web-scraping-with-r-message-that-javascript-is-disabled) question.

Comment: Hi @maydin. Thank you! I haven't been able to access the website following the post you suggested. This is the code I've tried:
```
remDr <-  RSelenium::remoteDriver(
  remoteServerAddr = "localhost",
  port = 4445L,
  browserName = "firefox"
)
remDr$open()
```
But I get the following error: >Error in checkError(res) : 
  Undefined error in httr call. httr output: length(url) == 1 is not TRUE>

Answer (score 0):

Today I re-tried my code and it works perfectly. I am not sure what was happening yesterday.

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.